# C++ map of std::function objects throws 'failed to specialize function template' error

Tags: c++, std-function, stdbind

I'm having hard time solving this issue related to my C++ school project. Basically, I need a map where the key is given `GUID` and the value is a member function of `MyClass`, which is a factory method for instances of derived classes of `BaseClass`, returned as a `BaseClass` pointer. The code would look like this:

```
class MyClass{
private:
    std::map<GUID, std::function<BaseClass*(ClassX*, ClassY*, const GUID*)>> map;
    template<typename T>
    BaseClass* createInstance(ClassX* classX, ClassY* classY, const GUID* guid);
public:
    BaseClass* getDerivedInstance(ClassX* classX, ClassY* classY, const GUID* guid);
    //...
};
```

Factory method:

```
template<typename T>
BaseClass* MyClass::createInstance(ClassX* classX, ClassY* classY, const GUID* guid){
    return new T(classX, classY, guid);
}
```

Method to call factory from the map:

```
BaseClass* MyClass::getInstance(ClassX* classX, ClassY* classY, const GUID* guid){
    return map[*guid](classX, classY, guid);
}
```

In constructor, i fill the map with factory methods (for now with just one) like this:

```
map[classGuid] = std::bind<BaseClass*>(&MyClass::createInstance<DerivedClassX>, this, std::placeholders::_3);
```

Class MyClass is a singleton, so it is filled just once.Code doesn't show any errors, but when compiled, MSVS2019 throws following errors:

> 'std::invoke': no matching overloaded function found
>   Failed to specialize function template 'unknown-type std::invoke(_Callable &&,_Types &&...) noexcept()'

I even tried doing something like

```
using plain_fnc = BaseClass* (MyClass::*)(ClassX*, ClassY*, const GUID*);
using bind_eq = decltype(std::bind<BaseClass*>(std::declval<plain_fnc>(),
    std::declval<MyClass*>(), std::declval<const decltype(std::placeholders::_3)&>()));

bind_eq factory = std::bind<BaseClass*>(&MyClass::createInstance<DerivedClassX>, this, std::placeholders::_3);
map[classGuid] = factory;
```

, which also doesn't show any errors, but ends with the same result when compiled.
I spent a few hours trying to solve this, but have no clue what could be the issue.Any help/tips greatly appreciated :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot the first placeholders:

```
map[classGuid] = std::bind<BaseClass*>(&MyClass::createInstance<DerivedClassX>, this,
    std::placeholders::_1, std::placeholders::_2, std::placeholders::_3);
```

You could also use a lambda:

```
map[classGuid] = [this](ClassX* classX, ClassY* classY, const GUID* guid) {
                     return createInstance<DerivedClassX>(classX, classY, guid);
                 };
```

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/5kZQQY)

Comment: Thank you! I was under the impression that using `std::placeholders_3` will work for 3 function parameters and didn't know, that it is just for the third parameter. Works fine now.

Comment: @markovd You're welcome! Using a lambda is probably the most popular way to do this nowadays. It's somewhat easier to read too i.m.o.